# storing and retrieving socket

Tags: node.js, socket.io

From what I can understand, once I create a socket, I can then create an array to store it with

```
userArray[socket.nickname]=socket;
```

I can then send a message to it with:

```
  io.sockets.socket(userArray[data.to]).emit('private message', tstamp(), socket.nickname, message);
```

The basic logic is to store a copy of each socket in an object, identified by nickname. When I want to send a message to that socket, I use the copy of the socket, and send the message via io.sockets.socket(id).emit(). The entire server code is below:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('user message', function (msg) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('user message', tstamp(), socket.nickname, msg);
    updateLog('user message', socket.nickname, msg);
  });

   socket.on('private message', function(data) {
        socket.get(data.nickname, function (err, name) {    
        console.log('Chat message by ', name);
        });
        updateLog('private message', socket.nickname, data.message);
        message=data.message;
        io.sockets.socket(userArray[data.to]).emit('private message', tstamp(), socket.nickname, message);
   });

  socket.on('get log', function () {
    updateLog(); // Ensure old entries are cleared out before sending it.
    io.sockets.emit('chat log', log);
  });

  socket.on('nickname', function (nick, fn) {
    var i = 1;
    var orignick = nick;
    while (nicknames[nick]) {
      nick = orignick+i;
      i++;
    }
    fn(nick);

    nicknames[nick] = socket.nickname = nick;
    userArray[socket.nickname]=socket;

    socket.set('nickname', nick, function () { socket.emit('ready'); });

    socket.broadcast.emit('announcement', nick + ' connected');
//    io.sockets.socket(userArray[nick]).emit('newID', 'Your name is: ' + nick, '. Your ID is: '+ userArray[nick]);
    io.sockets.emit('nicknames', nicknames);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what your actual question is, but if you've stored a socket object as the value of an object key (which is what you're doing; `userArray` is quite a misleading name since it's not an array), then you just call methods on the value. IOW, instead of

```
io.sockets.socket(userArray[data.to]).emit(...
```

you'd just write:

```
userArray[data.to].emit(...
```

Comment: That's what I meant :) - if userArray isn't an array, what is it? 
Also, if I didn't have to call io.sockets.socket(id).emit, but jut userArray[data.to].emit, does it mean that the whole io object is in the variable, not just that particular socket? 

the sockets object is a group of all the connected sockets, right? I only need to include that particular socket info, true? 

I hope that makes sense


BTW, That was the answer!

Comment: userArray is an object (that's a somewhat JavaScript-specific term, since in most languages "object" means "instance of a class" which is sometimes, but not always, the case in JS). In other languages, such a structure might be called an "associative array" (which is actually the pedantically-correct term, but it's too pedantic for common use) or a "hash" (which is, IMHO, too implementation-specific; such a structures is commonly implemented by a hash table, but that's not the only way to do it).

Comment: [continuing] In JS, a function is a first-class object (using yet another definition of object), meaning it can be stored as parts of other objects and assigned to variables, and it's also a closure (concept from functional programming; although JS syntactically looks like an "Algol-family" language like C, it's also partially descended from "LISP-family" languages like Scheme) which means that any instance of it has access to whatever variables were "around" it when it was created. At this point I'll suggest you read Douglas Crockford's "JavaScript: The Good Parts" which will clarify a lot.

Comment: wow...ok - some of it is terminology (associative array vs. objects), but in JS, only one kind of object can be defined as an associative array - since almost anything can be an object